# Reuse Powerpoint 2003 keyboard shortcut sequence in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

I've been using PPT 07 for a while now and I am losing time and productivity because the keyboard shortcuts from PPT 03 are not available anymore for some basic actions.

I don't know if this is due to my localized version of PPT (French), but this has become a nightmare to simply align object (I have to use my mous and click!?! Can you imagine!).

Example :
- Align Top
PPT 2003 : <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> (I guess it's <kbd>T</kbd> in English)

PPT 2007 : <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>-></kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>
Only because `Align` and `Push to background` share the same `A` shortcut!

- Same problem from `Group` or `Ungroup`, etc.

I have loosing so much time, so I really need to find a way to reverse the shortcut, or change them, but neither Google nor Superuser archive have given me any answer yet...

Again, may be it is link to Office localisation but still, it is very annoying.
Are you experiencing the same problem?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that can help you do this. There's certainly nothing in the Powerpoint global options.

The only suggestion I have would be to create your own custom macros linking to keyboard shutcuts that will do this.